# What kind of board is this, and where can I get some?

Tags: wood, flooring, measuring, tongue-and-groove

I have some tongue and groove floorboards from a bathroom.

They measure 0.83" thick and are probably about 90 years old.

Where can I get some boards that are equally thick? Tongue and groove is a bonus, but mainly I care about the thickness. They will be covered so I don't care about look. I'd even be willing to layer two boards together.

A plumber who worked on it replaced them with 0.75" boards but that left a noticeable sagging area.

I don't really know how to ask for it - is there a nominal name/trade name for 0.83" boards?

[image: wooden floor boards]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match that thickness exactly, you'll have to get something custom milled, or planed down from 1" stock.

The difference between .83" and 0.75" is just over a 16th of an inch.  Probably an extra layer of tar paper would make up the difference.

Comment: Tar paper wouldn't make up the difference here because the tongue and groove will keep it in place even with the extra backing.